Open set such that a subset of its topological boundary is a submanifold
Suppose that :

$U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$, such that $U=(\overline{U})^\circ$ (it is the interior of its closure).
There is a subset $B$ of the topological boundary Fr $U$ that is a $n-1$ submanifold without boundary of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Does that imply that $U\cup B$ is a manifold with boundary, with (manifold) boundary equal to $B$ ?
I know that in the case where $B$ is the whole Fr $U$, then $U\cup B=\overline U$ must be a manifold with boundary (see here for example : Smoothness of the boundary is the only obstruction for being a submanifold with boundary?) But the topological boundary is not necessarily the manifold boundary, if we don't add any other conditions. So that's why I suppose here that $U=(\overline{U})^\circ$.

What do you mean by a submanifold? Do you mean a smooth submanifold or a topological submanifold?

Here, I mean a smooth submanifold
